# Vue problem with table components and bootrstrap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a problem with  component and bootstrap-vue, even though everything is installed, when I use default example from documentation:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Nothing is being rendered on the page.
Version of my packages are:

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is the whole main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import parser from 'socket.io-msgpack-parser';
import vueConfig from '../vue.config';
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

const ws = 'http://localhost:3000';
export const SocketInstance = io(ws, { transports: ['websocket'], parser, query: {admin: true }});

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({connection: SocketInstance}), SocketInstance, BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = true;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

I couldn't use every single line from component but mostly this is it. Regarding App.vue it looks totaly like some default App.vue - just with name of my component.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <span class="title">
      <h3>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pie-chart" style="margin-right: 10px"></i>
        {{ textData.classVitals }}
      </h3>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>

    <template>
    <div>
      <b-table striped hover :items="items"></b-table>
    </div>
  </template>
  <h3 style="padding-bottom: 5px">{{ textData.teacherTable }}</h3>
</div>
</template>
import TeacherClassesModal from "./TeacherClassesModal.vue";
import TimeRangeModal from "./TimeRangeModal.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import Spinner from "vue-simple-spinner";


export default {
  name: "TeacherMonitoring",
  components: {
    showClasses: TeacherClassesModal,
    showTimeRange: TimeRangeModal,
    Spinner,
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
    fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'],
    items: [
          { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ],
    labels: [
      { text: 'ID', field: 'id' },
      { text: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      { text: 'Created', field: 'date_created' },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Is there any logging in the console? Please add it in your question.

Comment: Hi @Gabe, thre is no logging unfortunately. Table should appear when page is rendered - so on first load. What is strange to me though is that b-table element is indeed in source code (when I check in inspect element). But it is not present on the page. I will attach link for screenshot of page and you will see what is the result. [link](https://pasteboard.co/u29xXAKndAhB.png)

Comment: Could you please add your full component source to the question? So not only the template but also the script and style sections.

Comment: And also add your main.js please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the element in the console, you see that it is not processed by Vue, it is still a `b-table` tag. This is not an element the DOM can render. This means probably that Vue cannot find the component.

I think this might be because in your `main.js` you do not load the plugin `BootstrapVue` the right way. Now you put it as an option to the VueSocketIO plugin. This line:

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({connection: SocketInstance}), SocketInstance, BootstrapVue);
```

Should be:

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({connection: SocketInstance}), SocketInstance);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gabe, indeed bootstrap-vue was not loaded in to page properly. I have posted the answer what have I did.

Comment: That was exactly what I suggested, wasn't it? :-)

Comment: Yes, I will accept your answer we found the solution in the same time :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, thanks :-) Good luck with developing your app!

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was the problem, I have added BootstrapVue in Vue.use() line after Socket, when I separated them in 2 lines it worked out, so basically:

```
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({connection: SocketInstance}), SocketInstance);
```

Answer (score -1):

Does your main.js look something like this?

```
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Hey @sadkiviek, great you want to help, but this is not an answer to the question / solution to the problem.

Comment: Hi @ sadkiviek! Thanks for the answer. Yes indeed my main looks mostly like that.

Comment: Hi @gabe, I couldn't comment to ask for the main.js (reputation crap) and using mine could very well be a starting point to get a working solution (thus answering the question xd)